Regular expression of "odd number of a and odd number of b"
I want to create a regular expression of odd lengths of a and b. I found this solution on Stack Overflow:
((a+aaa)*(b+bbb)*(a+aaa)*(b+bbb)*(a+aaa)*)*(ab+ba)......... 

I found it to be correct from every angle.
But now my teacher said it is wrong. What am I missing?

Please make sure the formatting is legible: indent code by four spaces to prevent markdown from messing it up. Please also give some examples of things you want to match and things you do not, as I could not quite understand what the task is. Also clarify whether you have any restrictions. If you are asking what I think you might be asking, the easiest solution would involve a look-ahead, which is available in [tag:nsregularexpression], but is probably not if you are taking an automata class as the [tag:dfa] tag might imply.

For example, should the length of each substring of consecutive a (or b) be odd? This would match aba (1 a, 1 b, 1 a), but not aaba (2 a, 1 b, 1 a). Should the total amount of a (or b) in the string be odd? This would match abaa (3 a, 1 b), but not aba (2 a, 1 b). Should the entire string have an odd length, but be composed of just a and b? This would, again, match aba (3) but not abaa (4).

The regular expression you have given is not correct.
For instance, the Kleene star in (a+aaa)* would allow an even number of occurrences of the pattern a+aaa. So for instance it could match aa by applying a twice, and in the end any number of a would be matched by (a+aaa)*. It is no different from a*.
To solve this, realise that a valid input has an even number of characters (as odd+odd=even), and we can process pairs of characters at a time (aa, ab, ba, bb). When we consider the language where the alphabet is not {a, b}, but {aa, ab, ba, bb} (so we chop up the input by pairs), then a valid input will have an odd number of ab+ba.
We can represent that with the following DFA:

There are two states:

0: the state where the number of ab plus the number of ba is even. This is also the initial state.
1: the state where the number of ab plus the number of ba is odd. This is also the only accept state.

Now translate this to the regular expression syntax:
(aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)*((ab+ba)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)*)*

Here (aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)* will accept inputs with exactly one ab or one ba (always considering the language with pairs -- this is important!).
The second part, (ab+ba)(aa+bb)*(ab+ba)(aa+bb)* considers an additional transition from 1 to 0 and back to 1, so to add two occurrences of ab or ba. This second pattern can be repeated any number of times, as it will keep the total number of ab+ba odd.

Any feedback to this answer, @sachin?
